# How to point to a vector position inside a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, vector, cpu-word

I have a list of vectors with a (variable) number of words inside it, for example:

```
myList = ['\xa0\xa1\xa2', '\xa3\xa4\xa5']
```

(a list with two 3-word vectors)
Is there a way to point directly at the second position of the second vector?
I know that trying this won't do:

```
myWord = myList[1[1]]
```

Do I have to take a two-step approach? Make a copy of the vector from the list and then work with it directly?

```
myVector = myList[1]
myWord = myVector[1]
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
myList = ['\xa0\xa1\xa2', '\xa3\xa4\xa5']

myList[1][1] # this give you second position of second index
```

and for copy you can import `copy` module !

```
import copy

new_list=copy.copy(myList)
```

Your method (`some_list[index[inner_index]]`) is valid, but only if `index` is also indexable! For example:

```
some_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
indices = [0,0,0,1,1,1,3,3,6,2,4]
some_list[indices[3]]
# => some_list[1]
# => 2
```

Edit:
so as in the comments says you can also use `new_list=myList[:]` command ! that is more **pythonic** in this case !

Comment: you don't need copy, you can just do: `new_list = myList[:]`

Comment: yes its another way ! but i think using `copy` is more pythonic ! what you think?

Comment: i disagree, because copy requires an extra/otherwise unnecessary import. also, in this case, you actually don't need a copy because you're not mutating the list in any way.

Comment: yes in this case your right , thank for your reminding !

Comment: @Kasra I edited to add a blurb about when you would use the `my_list[index[other_index]]` approach

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take a two-step approach.
As stated by @Kasra, you can reference the second position of the second vector by:

```
    myWord = myList[1][1]
```

Explaining through, `myList[1]` references the list's second element (the second vector), then the next `[1]` references it's second element.